# TensorFlow: Quantize model using python before save

Tags: python, tensorflow, quantization

There are tutorials online showing how to quantize a `.pb` TensorFlow model, see:

https://petewarden.com/2016/05/03/how-to-quantize-neural-networks-with-tensorflow/

What I am wondering is if there is a way to quantize the graph using python before saving the `.pb` file with `tf.train.write_graph()`

In other words is there some function like `quantize(graph_def)` that I can run to quantize the graph to 8bit weights and operations before I save it, saving me the hassle of having to do it via the command line after saving the file (like the tutorial linked above outlines).

Comment: It will be really useful because otherwise we have to run heavy bazel build .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [quantize_weights](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms#quantize_weights) and [quantize_nodes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms#quantize_weights) rules for the Graph Transform Tool directly from Python. Here's an example:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/python/transform_graph_test.py#L76